# How and when does Vue store data in its underlying elements?

Tags: vuejs3

I am attempting to make use of the `dataset` attributes of elements, to enable data to be transferred from one item to another during a drag/drop process. But I am having some odd results depending on how Vues' `v-if` condition is used. The code below works as expected: if you click the 'move' button, then look at the underlying elements' datasets using the 'inspect' button, the dataset for the second item changes.....

```
<script setup>
  import {  onMounted,ref,reactive } from 'vue'
  const thisData = reactive(['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE'])

  var items = [];
  var moves = 0;

  onMounted(() => {
    items= document.querySelectorAll('.swappable') ;
    inspect();

  });
  function inspect() {
    for (let n=0; n < 5; n++)  {
      let data = items[n].dataset.transfer;
      const elem = document.getElementById(idString(n+100));
      elem.innerText = 'id: ' + items[n].id + ' :' + data ;
    }
  }
  function move() {
      thisData[1] = thisData[0];
      ++moves;
  }

  function localTest(x) {
        return x > 2;
  }
  function globalTest(chip) {
    return moves > 0;
    
  } 
  function idString(n) {
    return 'btn'+n;
  }
  function dataTransfer(n) {
    return 'data stored: '+n;
  }

</script>

<template>
   <template v-for="(item,n) in thisData" :key="n" >
     <button  v-if="localTest(n)"  style="background-color: lightblue;" class="swappable"
        :data-transfer = dataTransfer(item)
        :id=idString(n)
        > {{ item }} 
     </button>
     <button    v-else   style="background-color: lightgreen;" class="swappable"
        :data-transfer = dataTransfer(item)
        :id=idString(n)
        > {{ item}} 
    </button>
     <p :id=idString(n+100) >   </p>
   </template>
     <button  @click="inspect()">Inspect Element Data</button >
    <p></p>
   <button  @click="move()">Copy btn 1 to btn 2</button >
</template>
```

... but if the `v-if` test is changed to `globalTest(n)` instead of `localTest(n)`, the dataset *does not* change.
My app needs to use a test using a 'global' (a reactive one in fact) but I also need to access the changed dataset.

The effect [can be seen here](https://play.vuejs.org/#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), by editing the `v-if` test.

Comment: I only added `moves` to show the problem, it doesn't actually do anything useful. All the components themselves update correctly; it's the data behind that isn't updating with the 'global' test.

Comment: I don't think there's anything here that is unneccesary! It's already taken me several hours to distil my original code to the minumum needed to show the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting the resulting page using the browser toolbox shows that the elements are updating correctly even when using `globalTest`.

The problem is that you are using references to detached elements, which obviously don't update. You shouldn't store elements in a simple array when using Vue, as Vue sometimes changes and replaces elements when updating the component, causing the references you stored to become obsolete.

Instead, you should use [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for):

> `ref` is a special attribute, similar to the `key` attribute discussed in the `v-for` chapter. It allows us to obtain a direct reference to a specific DOM element or child component instance after it's mounted.

In your case, we can replace `var items = []` with `var items = ref([])` and all other references to `items` with `items.value`, then remove `items= document.querySelectorAll('.swappable') ;` from `onMounted`.
We should also add `ref="items"` to the button.

This resolves issue, as now the references are automatically updated when Vue replaces an element.

Here is the fixed code:

```js
<script setup>
  import {  onMounted,ref,reactive } from 'vue'
  const thisData = reactive(['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE'])

  var items = ref([]);
  var moves = 0;

  onMounted(() => {
    inspect();
  });
  function inspect() {
    for (let n=0; n < 5; n++)  {
      let data = items.value[n].dataset.transfer;
      const elem = document.getElementById(idString(n+100));
      elem.innerText = 'id: ' + items.value[n].id + ' :' + data ;
    }
  }
  function move() {
      thisData[1] = thisData[0];
      ++moves;
  }

  function localTest(x) {
        return x > 2;
  }
  function globalTest(chip) {
    return moves > 0;
    
  } 
  function idString(n) {
    return 'btn'+n;
  }
  function dataTransfer(n) {
    return 'data stored: '+n;
  }

</script>

<template>
   <template v-for="(item,n) in thisData" :key="n" >
     <button  v-if="globalTest(n)"  style="background-color: lightblue;" class="swappable"
        :data-transfer = dataTransfer(item)
        :id=idString(n)
        ref="items"
        > {{ item }} 
     </button>
     <button    v-else   style="background-color: lightgreen;" class="swappable"
        :data-transfer = dataTransfer(item)
        :id=idString(n)
        ref="items"
        > {{ item}} 
    </button>
     <p :id=idString(n+100) >   </p>
   </template>
     <button  @click="inspect()">Inspect Element Data</button >
    <p></p>
   <button  @click="move()">Copy btn 1 to btn 2</button >
</template>
```

Comment: As per the code in my question, your answer is a solution so I have marked it as correct. Sadly, though, in the real world my project is far more complex and after much restructuring I still have the same problem. I guess this is one potential pitfall of a 'minimum reproducible example' - I have created a simpler illness with the same symptoms but a different cause :( - I will come back here later if/when I solve it.

Comment: @quilkin I did notice that in your example, when using `localTest` the `v-if` was only triggered on creation, whereas with `globalTest`, the `v-if` was also triggered after clicking "copy". Maybe it's related somehow. Good luck finding the root cause.