# vue3js - why are keys not showing correctly in devtools?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-devtools

I am having strange problems with a vue3 app and have started to use the [vue3 devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) add-in to see what is going on.
In one project, I am seeing all the `:key` values showing as zero:

[image: snip from devtools]

although I am setting these values correctly in the template:

```
<template v-for="(chip,c) in row" :key=idString(0,r,c)>
    <v-chip v-if="!chip.used" size="x-large" variant="outlined" class="copyable changeclass"
        @dropped="drop"
        :data-transfer = myJson(r,c,chip.name)
        :id=idString(0,r,c)
```

(the `id` value is shown correctly so I know that `idString()` is correct - but whatever value I add for `:key` the result shows as zero in the devtools.)

I have another (very similar) project where the key values are reported (almost) correctly:

[image: snip from devtools]

'Almost' because the values shown have an extra '0' in added to what I asked for (should be just 32,33,34,,,).

Now, the second project is not showing the same problem as the first ([described in an earlier question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76299147/how-and-when-does-vue-store-data-in-its-underlying-elements)) so I am wondering if these incorrect key values are the cause.
I did wonder if the `vue` installation was corrupted, but have now uninstalled and re-installed, was running `vue 3.3.2`, now running  `vue 3.2.47` (same as the working project) and the strange `key` behaviour remains.

Comment: It's unknown if the problem is specific to devtools or something else. Any way, it requires a way to reproduce.

Comment: The `<template>` is the keyed element, and that key is not passed down to the v-chip.  It may display as 0 due to some behavior with devtools understanding the elements are rendered with a v-for and expecting the `v-for` to be on `<v-chip>` instead... Not sure.  It is just devtools though and shouldn't have any affect on the app working properly.  I personally would disregard it